# Color of text doesn't change

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making submarine game in pygame, but text in menu doesn't want to change color when I cover it with mouse. I tried to refresh display at that part, and changing where if sentences are, but nothing seemed to help. There wasn't any syntax errors. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption('Podmornca')
run = True
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
colour1 = black
colour2 = black
colour3 = black
location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
background = pygame.image.load('meni.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont('bauhaus93', 20)
text1 = font.render('SINGLE PLAYER', 1, barva1)
text2 = font.render('MULTIPLAYER', 1, barva2)
text3 = font.render('QUIT', 1, barva3)
pygame.display.update()
def grafika():
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(text1, (100, 200))
    screen.blit(text2, (100, 250))
    screen.blit(text3, (100, 300))
    pygame.display.update()     
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    if location == (100, 200):
        colour1 = red
    if polozaj == (100, 250):
        colour2 = red
    if location == (100, 300):
        colour3 = red
    grafika()
pygame.quit()
```

Can anyone tell me, where I messed up and how to fix it?

Comment: (I am assuming that *colourX* and *barvaX* are supposed to be the same thing, just incompletely translated to English.)  The problem appears to be that you only rendered your text items *once*, prior to the main loop; these items aren't going to magically change just because you changed a variable that was used in their original creation.

Comment: You have a similar problem with `location`: you only set it once, it's not going to magically update itself as the mouse moves.  It's extremely unlikely that the mouse position is ever going to be *exactly* equal to `(100, 200)` or the other two coordinates you're checking for: you need to check the position being within a rectangular area instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the mouse position in the main application loop.

Render the each text twice, once in black and once in red:

```py
text1 = font.render('SINGLE PLAYER', 1, black)
text2 = font.render('MULTIPLAYER', 1, black)
text3 = font.render('QUIT', 1, black)
text1red = font.render('SINGLE PLAYER', 1, red)
text2red = font.render('MULTIPLAYER', 1, red)
text3red = font.render('QUIT', 1, red)
```

Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to detect the if the mouse is on the text. Draw the red text if the mouse is on the text and draw the blcok text else. For instance:

```py
def drawText(text, textRed, pos):
    location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if text.get_rect(topleft = pos).collidepoint(location):
        screen.blit(textRed, pos)
    else:
        screen.blit(text, pos)
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Podmornca')
run = True
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
background = pygame.image.load('meni.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont('bauhaus93', 20)

text1 = font.render('SINGLE PLAYER', 1, black)
text2 = font.render('MULTIPLAYER', 1, black)
text3 = font.render('QUIT', 1, black)
text1red = font.render('SINGLE PLAYER', 1, red)
text2red = font.render('MULTIPLAYER', 1, red)
text3red = font.render('QUIT', 1, red)

def drawText(text, textRed, pos):
    location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if text.get_rect(topleft = pos).collidepoint(location):
        screen.blit(textRed, pos)
    else:
        screen.blit(text, pos)

def grafika():
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    drawText(text1, text1red, (100, 200))
    drawText(text2, text2red, (100, 250))
    drawText(text3, text3red, (100, 300))
    pygame.display.update()     

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    grafika()
pygame.quit()
```